# Android ListView with Sqlite access

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I build a activity with a listview.
Populate it by use of sqlite.
But, when I write a few records into the DB and than show the result in the listView.
He doesn't show all the records.

Thank a lot for you help.

debug screen

D/DstNote: Find all arrow info.
D/DstNote: Records : 3
D/DstNote: 454554 
D/DstNote: 45545454 
D/DstNote: Find all arrow info.
D/DstNote: Records : 3 
D/DstNote: position : 0 
D/DstNote: position : 1

Méthode to read the data into DB

```
 public ArrayList<ArrowInfo> getAllArrowInfo() {
    Log.d("DstNote", "Find all arrow info.");

    ArrayList<ArrowInfo> allArrowInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] selectedColomns = new String[] {
            COLOMN_ID, COLOMN_ARROW_REF, COLOMN_TYPE_ARC, COLOMN_FIELD_IN, COLOMN_FIELD_OUT
    };

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, selectedColomns, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    Log.d("DstNote", ""+c.getCount());

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DstNote", cursorToArrow(c).getArrowRef());
        allArrowInfo.add(cursorToArrow(c));

    }

    return allArrowInfo;
}
```

the adapter

```
class ArrowInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<ArrowInfo> allArrayInfo;

    public ArrowInfoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrowInfo> allArrayInfo) {
        ctx = context;
        this.allArrayInfo = allArrayInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (allArrayInfo != null) ? allArrowInfo.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ArrowInfo getItem(int position) {
        return allArrowInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ArrowInfo currentArrowInfo = allArrowInfo.get(position);

        View itemView = convertView;

        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.simple_listview_arraw_info_item, parent, false);
        }

        Log.d("DstNote", "position : " + position);

        TextView refArrow = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.refArrow);
        TextView arcType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arctype_TextView);
        TextView field = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_textview);

        refArrow.setText(currentArrowInfo.getArrowRef());
        arcType.setText(currentArrowInfo.getTypeArc().name());
        field.setText((currentArrowInfo.getIndoor() == 0) ? "IN" : "OUT");

        itemView.setTag(currentArrowInfo);

        return itemView;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        /*allArrowInfo.clear();
        allArrowInfo.addAll(model.getAllArrowInfo());*/
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and the create méthod

```
allArrowInfo = model.getAllArrowInfo();

    for (ArrowInfo item : allArrowInfo) {
        Log.d("DstNote", item.getArrowRef());
    }

    adapter = new ArrowInfoAdapter(getBaseContext(), allArrowInfo);

    registerForContextMenu(arrowInfoListView);

    arrowInfoListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not a custom `BaseAdapter`

Comment: I use a Custum layout.

Comment: it doesnt matter, see second `SimpleCursorAdapter`'s constructor parameter

Comment: How can I do to get the information object from SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: by reading its Cursor

Comment: give me an exemple

Comment: cursor.getString(0)

Comment: cursorAdapter.getItem(1) what kind of object is it.

Comment: call `getClass()` on it, but it is really easier to check [CursorAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#244) sources